# How do I unmount a drive "not mounted by HAL"?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, mount

I'm running CentOS in a virtual machine (VMware) and booting from an `iso`, is it possible to unmount the 'drive' I booted from?

I get something along the lines of cannot unmount because it was *not mounted by HAL*...

Is it possible to force it to unmount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not mounted by HAL means you can't unmount it as a normal user so you need to use your `root` account to do so.

So run:

```
su
(enter your root password)
umount /mnt/wherever
```

Comment: Alternatively you can also use sudo.

Comment: Sure, but sudo is less likely to be the default on CentOS.